# Expected value does not exist

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

If *X* has the probability mass function $$\mathbb P(X=n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2n^2}$$
 and we are asked to find the expected value, then

$$\mathbb E\left[X\right]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \frac{6}{\pi^2n^2}
=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2}$$

Which surely is the harmonic series, which diverges. Therefore, the expected value does not exist. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that the expected value doesn't exist.

In this case, we could say that the expected value diverges to $\infty$; there are also two-sided versions of the example for which both the positive and negative parts are divergent.

Comment: I'm enough of an analyst that "exists" usually means "exists and is finite" for me.